# How to add click event and Image for ControlPaint.DrawButton()

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have drawn the button using the below code. How can I add the image and click event for this button?

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
 base.OnPaint(e);
 ControlPaint.DrawButton(e.Graphics, 20, 20, 300, 40, ButtonState.Flat);}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the most basic Windows.Forms structure? If so you can access the Buttons properties once in the designer, typically bottom right corner of VS. Double click the button in the designer will auto create an OnClick handler.

Comment: What IDE are you using to implement your app? If you are experimenting without Visual Studio, (do not have designer support), the solution would be different. But if you have Visual Studio, as others suggested, use the editor to add a button from the toolbox and you will have access to all its properties and events in the Properties window (right click button and select properties, or, click the button and press F4)